# Editing Pages that Have Already Been Published

Tags: pages, maintenance

Sorry for the simple question.

I've published a page. Let's say that I now need to make changes to the page. Can I simply edit it, after it's been published? Or should I use a maintnenace mode? If someone tries to view the page at the same time that I'm editing it, will they be greeted by an error message?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the page at any time after it is published. I would not recommend using maintenance mode, as then your entire site will be unavailable while you are editing the page.

When you are editing, your site is unaffected until you click "Update" and save the changes to the published post.

No users will receive error messages when you edit, however they may see the old content until they refresh.

Comment: good timing! :)

Comment: haha, I guess so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can edit your page. Doing so shouldn't cause any front-end problems. Visitors won't see your in-process edits until you save the edits.

Note: you should almost never need to worry about - or use - "Maintenance mode" manually. It is primarily something that WordPress uses internally.